# Check if file exists in 2 directories using ASP or PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, file-io, intersection

I am looking for a way to compare 2 directories to see if a file exists in both. What I want to do is delete a file in 1 of the directories if it exists in both.

I can either use **`ASP`** or **`PHP`**.

Example:

```
/devices/1001
/devices/1002
/devices/1003
/devices/1004
/devices/1005

/disabled/1001
/disabled/1002
/disabled/1003
```

So since `1001, 1002, 1003` exist in **/disabled/**, I want to remove them from **/devices/** and only be left with `1004, 1005` in **/devices/**.

Comment: Does you current code not work? if not why? Or are you looking for a better way to do it?

Comment: The test I am using, 20 of the files in devices all exist in desabled, 2 in devices do not exist in disbaled, my code tells me they ALL do not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `scandir()` to get an array of the file names in each directory, and then using `array_intersect()` to find elements of the first array that are present in any additional arguments given.

http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

```
<?php
$devices = scandir('/i/auth/devices/');
$disabled = scandir('/i/auth/disabled/');

foreach(array_intersect($devices, $disabled) as $file) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
        continue;
    unlink('/i/auth/devices/'.$file);
}
```

Applied as a function including checking the directories are valid:

```
<?php
function removeDuplicateFiles($removeFrom, $compareTo) {
    $removeFromDir = realpath($removeFrom);
    if ($removeFromDir === false)
        die("Invalid remove from directory: $removeFrom");

    $compareToDir = realpath($compareTo);
    if ($compareToDir === false)
        die("Invalid compare to directory: $compareTo");

    $devices = scandir($removeFromDir);
    $disabled = scandir($compareToDir);

    foreach(array_intersect($devices, $disabled) as $file) {
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
            continue;
        unlink($removeFromDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
    }
}

removeDuplicateFiles('/i/auth/devices/', '/i/auth/disabled/');
```

Comment: awesome, this worked perfectly, and is going to increase my productivity, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy with PHP - in this example we set the two base directories and the filename... this could easily be an array in a `foreach()` loop.  Then we check in both directories to see if it does indeed reside in each.  If so, we delete from the first. This can be easily modified to delete from the second.

See below:

```
<?php 

$filename = 'foo.html';
$dir1 = '/var/www/';
$dir2 = '/var/etc/';
if(file_exists($dir1 . $filename) && file_exists($dir2 . $filename)){
  unlink($dir1 . $filename);
}
```

Comment: what if I dont know the name of $filename? There are alot of random files generated, so the filename is not known at first. I need it to iterate through both directories and compare filenames.

Comment: Then @jacob's answer below is exactly what you're looking for. Plug-and-play!

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($handle = opendir('/disabled/')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            unlink('/devices/' . $file);            
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In php, use this for checking if the file exists.... it will return true or false...

file_exists(relative file_path)

Answer (score 0):

For each file in devices check to see if it exists in disabled using the disabled path and the file name from devices.

```
<%

    Set fso = server.createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set devices   = fso.getfolder(server.mappath("/i/auth/devices/"))
    Set disabledpath  = server.mappath("/i/auth/disabled/")

    For each devicesfile in devices.files
        if directory.fileExists(disablepath & devicesfile.name ) Then 

            Response.Write " YES "
            Response.write directoryfile.name & "<br>"

        Else

            Response.Write " NO "
            Response.write directoryfile.name & "<br>"

        End if 
    Next    

%>
```